# Comparing syntax to feof

Tags: c, feof

Hi guys i am wirting a c programme here and i am trying to print two lines from a text file at a time the problem is that when on the last line if the lines are odd, 3 lines 5 lines. It will print the last line twice.I cant find the comparison of if function for thsi particualr question. is it a bool?
I am trying ferror(file) currently

```
    FILE *file;

    printf("Hello!\n");
    printf("Please input file name(without.txt):\n");

    scanf("%s", input);
    strcat(input,".txt");
    file = fopen( input , "r" );

    while(!(feof(file)))
    {

        for(i=0; i<2; i++){
        **if(feof(file)==ferror(file))**
        {
            printf("File ended");
                return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            fgets(return_char, 200, file);
            printf("%s\n", return_char);
        }
    }

    }
```

Example of input :

i have a cat

i have a dog

i have a cow

Expected output :

first round

i have a cat

i have a dog

second round :

i have a cow

Current output  :
first round :

i have a cat

i have a dog

second round :

i have a cow

i have a cow

Comment: “while( !feof( file ) )” is always wrong.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong

Comment: hi there thanks for replying.
i have changed and am using what you have suggested, it still consist of the same error and the first letter is missing. 

output now is 

  have a cat
i have a dog
second output 
  have a cow
  have a cow

Comment: Stop using `feof` and `ferror` entirely. Loop until `fgets` fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
        int i;
        FILE *file;
        char input[20],return_char[50],ch;
        printf("Hello!\n");
        printf("Please input file name(without.txt):\n");

        scanf("%s", input);
        strcat(input,".txt");
        file = fopen( input , "r" );
        i=2;
        while(fgets(return_char, 200, file))
        {
                if(i==0){ 
                        printf("Do you want to continue(y/n)\n");
                        scanf(" %c",&ch);
                        if(ch == 'y'){
                                printf("%s\n", return_char); 
                                i=1; // making i=1 to read further line.
                        }
                        else{
                                fclose(file);
                                return 0;
                        }
                }
                else{
                        printf("%s\n", return_char);
                        i--;
                }
        }
}
```

In this program when `i=0` the `return_char` will have the third line of the file. So i am making `i=1` again to read next line and so on.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour you observe is typical of `foef`, which checks for end-of-file after the fact.

It is usually better to use the return values of the file reading functions (`fgets`, `fgetc`, `fread` etc.) instead of `feof`. Your loop will then look like this:

```
while (1) {
    for(i=0; i<2; i++) {
        if (fgets(return_char, 200, file) == NULL) {
            printf("File ended");
            return 0;
        }            
        printf("%s", return_char);            
    }
    printf("--\n");
}
```

Or, without explicit loop over `i` and outer infinite loop framework:

```
i = 0;
while (fgets(return_char, 200, file)) {
    printf("%s", return_char);            
    if (i == 1) printf("--\n");
    i = 1 - i;
}

printf("File ended");
return 0;
```

Comment: `while (fgets(return_char, 200, file) != NULL) {` or `while (fgets(return_char, 200, file)) {`

Comment: @wildplasser: Oh, of course: the second example has the condition wrong (and I prefer your second syntax). I'll fix, thanks.

Comment: @MOehm the only problem left is that i will be prompting user for an input for the second round of loop which i can't be using while(1)

Comment: @user3809384: I don't understand what you want, I'm afraid. Do you want to prompt the user interactively for the second string if the file has an odd number of lines?

Comment: Nope. For the first two lines it will appear automatically, for the following 2 user will be prompted to continue or exit. The .txt that will be read are given off 3 lines. When user chooses to continue, it returns the third line twice.  i have tried many different loops it either works giving me all 3 lines altogether or 4 lines with repeated 3rd line all this while. @MOehm

Comment: @user3809384: But that is totally unrelated to the original `feof` question and has something to do with reading user input with `scanf` or some such, no?